# Cold indicator light is on and my car has trouble starting. How do I fix?

Tags: toyota, starting, yaris

I have a 2013 Toyota Yaris and ever since the temp outside dropped (not even that cold, around 20-30 degrees Fahrenheit), my car’s cold indicator light has turned on and has been having trouble starting. When I turn the key, it will turn once and then I have to hold the key until it starts turning faster until it’s on. After it’s on and it has been running for a while, I can turn my car off and on again just fine. The battery is pretty new. I have no idea what’s wrong with it.

Comment: It sounds like a weak battery or possibly a poor battery connection or a damaged battery cable.  You might check those or take and have them checked at a shop.

Comment: 20-30 Fahrenheit is below freezing. In cold weather, it is not at all unusual to have to turn over the engine a few times before it will fire.

Comment: Is it a diesel? Have you allowed enough time for the pre-heat / glow plugs to warm up?

Comment: It takes regular unleaded

Comment: _Not even that cold - around 20 degrees_, laughs in Texan.  How long have you had the car?  Did it start better last winter?

Comment: "battery is pretty new"  This sounds like a bad battery or bad connection.